# HTML/CSS How to put my th at the same level in the same height in a datable?

Tags: html, css, html-table, datatable, bootstrap-5

For the display of my th, I want my first 2 ths to be put on top like the last th without using absolute position if possible so that the red square is always next to the first span

```css
table.dataTable thead span.sort-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: red;
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting span.sort-icon { background: url('http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/integration/bootstrap/images/sort_both.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc span.sort-icon { background: url('http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/integration/bootstrap/images/sort_asc.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc span.sort-icon { background: url('http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/integration/bootstrap/images/sort_desc.png') no-repeat center right; }

table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled span.sort-icon { background: url('http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/integration/bootstrap/images/sort_asc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled span.sort-icon { background: url('http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/integration/bootstrap/images/sort_desc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right; }

.dataTable thead th {
  position: sticky; top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table dataTable table-hover display nowrap no-footer pb-5" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr >
      <th data-key="from">
        <span>Firstaname</span>
        <span class="sort-icon datatable-span"/>
      </th>
      <th data-key="to">
        <span class="datatable-span" data-key-translate="common.to">Lastname</span>
        <span class="sort-icon datatable-span"/>
      </th>
      <th data-key="creator">
        <span style="" data-key-translate="common.auctionCreator">Demand</span><br>
        <span style="" data-key-translate="common.internalOnly">Duration (min)</span><br>
        <span style="" data-key-translate="common.internalOnly">Date of demand</span>
        <span class="sort-icon datatable-span"/>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: do you want like this ?? 
https://ibb.co/WzdqDPt

Comment: Yes ! I want it to be like this

Comment: You can add   vertical-align: top !important; for th. For example:  `.dataTable thead th {
  position: sticky; top: 0; vertical-align: top !important;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align: top !important;` for th.

```css
table.dataTable thead span.sort-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 5px;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: red;
}

table.dataTable thead .sorting span.sort-icon { background: url('http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/integration/bootstrap/images/sort_both.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc span.sort-icon { background: url('http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/integration/bootstrap/images/sort_asc.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc span.sort-icon { background: url('http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/integration/bootstrap/images/sort_desc.png') no-repeat center right; }

table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc_disabled span.sort-icon { background: url('http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/integration/bootstrap/images/sort_asc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right; }
table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc_disabled span.sort-icon { background: url('http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/3cfcc339e89/integration/bootstrap/images/sort_desc_disabled.png') no-repeat center right; }

.dataTable thead th {
  position: sticky; top: 0; vertical-align: top !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table dataTable table-hover display nowrap no-footer pb-5" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr >
      <th data-key="from">
        <span>Firstaname</span>
        <span class="sort-icon datatable-span"/>
      </th>
      <th data-key="to">
        <span class="datatable-span" data-key-translate="common.to">Lastname</span>
        <span class="sort-icon datatable-span"/>
      </th>
      <th data-key="creator">
        <span style="" data-key-translate="common.auctionCreator">Demand</span><br>
        <span style="" data-key-translate="common.internalOnly">Duration (min)</span><br>
        <span style="" data-key-translate="common.internalOnly">Date of demand</span>
        <span class="sort-icon datatable-span"/>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```